# May a Jew be a professional beat boxer?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

(Not to be confused with [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26048/5).)

Are there any halachic problems with a Jew being a professional beat boxer? (For those unfamiliar, click the speaker icon [here](http://translate.google.com/#en/de/pv%20zk%20pv%20pv%20zk%20pv%20zk%20kz%20zk%20pv%20pv%20pv%20zk%20pv%20zk%20zk%20pzk%20pzk%20pvzkpkzvpvzk%20kkkkkk%20bsch) for audio.)

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: That's an amazing audio!

Comment: Audio doesn't work anymore :(

Comment: @DoubleAA, I know. I'm so sad!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per Medrash Purim

> Bamidbar 23:21 says לא הביט און translated as, "it is not a sin to be
>   a beat". However there are those who translate as "Do not be a beat,
>   it is a sin". They base it on the Posuk in Eicha 5:1 which says  הביט
>   וראה את חרפתנו translated as "He beat, and he saw our shame".

Comment: that makes no sense. +1