# May a Jewish professional boxer box a Jewish professional beat boxer?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

(Not to be confused with [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26202/may-a-jew-be-a-professional-beat-boxer).)

Are there any halachic problems with a Jewish boxer boxing a Jewish beat boxer?

**This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).**

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox_in_Socks

Answer (score 7):

The biggest problem will probably be finding a large enough box.

After that make sure to poke some air holes.

Comment: are you sure we shouldn't rather punch some air holes?

Answer (score 7):

The boxer can box the beat boxer provided that the beat boxer can beat the boxer. ( עין משכתב הב"ח על ח""מ בק:ס).

Comment: Do you mean 'ק"ב ס?

Comment: No, though it probably should be ב"ק:ס...or perhaps it was ב"כ:ז, I don't have my seforim with me since they've all been boxed away.

Comment: To put it in English: I see your post as referring to the Bach on Choshen Mishpat Beis-Kuf:Samech. I was asking if you meant Kuf-Beis:Samech. Perhaps it shows up differently on your computer.

Comment: Well, if you put it into English they are the same ;) except for our purpose, for which they would be different (B"K:S vs. K"B:S).

Comment: Well, I was asking because I see neither a 102:60 nor a 60:102, whether numbered by the Bach or by the Shulchan Aruch, so it seems that the Hebrew may be a little bit off.

Comment: @ba say בקס out loud.

Comment: Oh, I apologize, I can't believe I missed that. (+1)

Answer (score 4):

Well, assuming that it's prohibited to be a boxer, and it's prohibited to be a beat boxer, then none of their punches will land. Because *ein issur chal al issur.*

Unless... one of them uses a one-two combo where the second strike involves hitting him with a copy of the [Even HaEzel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_HaEzel), because then you have *Isser Mosif*.

It's then possible he can give his opponent a black eye in the shape of a *nekuda nifla'ah.*