# Are animal fats cooked with dairy issur hanaah

Tags: halacha, meat-and-milk, yoreh-deah, issurei-hanaa, chelev

According to [Leviticus 7:24](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.7.24) forbidden fats from non shechita’d animals may be used for any purpose but eating. Therefore, is it permissible to cook them with dairy and/or sell them mixed with dairy? Or is that still issur hanaah despite this Passuk saying it can be used for non eating purposes? What is the Halacha regarding this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Aruch HaShulchan Yoreh Deah 87:12](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.87.12?lang=he) (basing himself on the opinion of Rambam) writes that it is forbidden to cook *chelev* (forbidden animal fats) with milk, but that after the fact one can derive benefit from such a mixture.

However, [Peri Megadim in his introduction to Basar BeChalav](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pri_Megadim_on_Yoreh_De%27ah%2C_Introduction_to_the_Laws_of_Meat_with_Milk.9?lang=he), while noting this opinion of Rambam, writes that he believes that one may not benefit from *chelev* cooked with milk.

Comment: The halacha here is what underpins this Purim Torah, by the way: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26216/21 . (Generally we say that one prohibition can stack onto another if it broadens it, however the Rambam's "wondrous point" is that if the prohibition on benefit is essentially a form of a prohibition on eating, then you can't stack them. The more common question is beef that wasn't kosher slaughtered, which was then cooked in milk. (Not everyone agrees with the Rambam on this.) Just because the Torah said "it can be used", doesn't mean you can't then mess it up further.

Comment: Certainly if you took that animal fat and then put it in a city which was then condemned for worshiping idols, it becomes prohibited from all benefit, as the latter prohibition isn't about "eating."